# How do I prove the existence of infinite union in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

Given an infinite set of sets A - how can I prove in ZFC that the union of all the elements of A exists?

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Axiom of union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the axiom of union which assert this.

The axiom states that if $A$ is a set, then there exists a set $B$ such that $B=\bigcup A$, that is to say

> For every $x$, $x\in B$ if and only if there exists $y$ such that $y\in A$ and $x\in y$.